# Send funds to owner after each buy or after several?

Tags: security, gas-price, gas-estimate, wallet-transfer, crowdsale

I copied and modified smart contracts from [TenX](https://etherscan.io/address/sale.tenxpay.eth#code) and [EOS](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd0a6e6c54dbc68db5db3a091b171a77407ff7ccf#code).

TenX sends funds to their wallet after every purchase from a buyer:

```
function createTokens(address recipient) public isUnderHardCap saleIsOn payable {
    uint rate = exchangeRate.getRate("ETH");
    uint tokens = rate.mul(msg.value).div(1 ether);
    token.mint(recipient, tokens);
    require(multisigVault.send(msg.value));
    TokenSold(recipient, msg.value, tokens, rate);
  }
```

Whereas EOS does not.  EOS seems to collect funds every once in a while:

```
// Crowdsale owners can collect ETH any number of times
    function collect() auth {
        assert(today() > 0); // Prevent recycling during window 0
        exec(msg.sender, this.balance);
        LogCollect(this.balance);
    }
```

Doesn't it get too expensive (with gas) to do it TenX's way, especially if there are thousands of transactions?  Is it insecure to do it EOS's way, because they are leaving funds on the contract?

Which is the better method?

UPDATED 2017-08-25

Maybe the better way is something in between.  I'm thinking of adding the following code, which is to send only if contract's balance is over 50 ETH and also give the owner the option to disable/enable this.  If this the best method or compromise?:

```
  bool public autoSend = true;

  function createTokens(address recipient) public payable {
    require(recipient != 0x0);
    require(validPurchase());
    uint256 tokens = rate.mul(msg.value).div(1 ether);
    require(token.mint(recipient, tokens));
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(msg.value);
    if (autoSend && this.balance > 50000000000000000000) { // > 50 ETH
        uint256 amount = this.balance;
        Vault.transfer(this.balance);
        LogCollect(amount);
    }
    LogBuy(recipient, msg.value, tokens, rate);
  }

  function collect() onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
    uint256 amount = this.balance;
    Vault.transfer(this.balance);
    LogCollect(amount);
    return amount;
  }

  function setAutoSend(bool _auto) public onlyOwner {
    autoSend = _auto;
  }
```

Comment: As I said below, I don't like this "in the between" solution :) Anyway if you want to use it please note you can save some ethers removing the "amount" local variable. Just log before the transfer: if the transfer fail it throws exception, then state is reverted and logs are never emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to follow EOS design choice:

- It costs less in terms of overall GAS spent
- Transfer costs are payed from the recipent of the funds, not from senders (this seems to me more fair)
- It uses a best practice about sending funds. From [Solidity
  documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-pattern):

> The recommended method of sending funds after an effect is using the
>   withdrawal pattern.
>   Although the most intuitive method of sending Ether, as a result of an
>   effect, is a direct send call, this is not recommended as it
>   introduces a potential security risk. You may read more about this on
>   the [Security Considerations](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#security-considerations) page.

Comment: Just to clarify--this is warning against a send to an arbitrary address. In the case of the EOS smart contract, where the send address is hard coded into the smart contract, this doesn't technically apply, but your point is not incorrect.

Comment: I don't think that's the point. The EOS send address is not hardcoded: it's the sender of the TX. If it pass the auth check (it must be the owner) then contract send funds to it. But EOS owner can change the contract owner, so in this term it's not different from TenX contract, they both sends funds somewhere that can be determined after the contract creation. The difference is the pattern used: send funds just after something is happened (TenX) or store funds in the contract and get them later (EOS)

Comment: Thomas is right, the solidity documentation recomends agains the push pattern when the destination address is unknown. In any case the address is know but the EOS team, even if they can change it.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. In EOS the address is not hardcoded, and it can be changed anytime, and this is also true just before the execution of my TX, so the address is unknown to me and to the contract code until my TX is executed. On the contrary, if the recipient of funds is fixed and immutable, you can check it: so if it is a normal account or a contract with a "safe" fallback function, it is safe to send funds in any case and this pattern does not apply. Is this correct?

Comment: The withdrawal pattern is used to make the person retrieving the funds pay for the gas (pull mode). In push mode the person sending the funds pays for the gas. If you do not control the destination, you might be subject to a recursive attack. But if you control the destination then there's no problem. In most crowdsales the destination is know in advance that is why it is not required to implement a pull mode operation, and push mode is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a security vault like a multisig wallet or a [specialized contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/RefundVault.sol) is a security measure.

You do not needed them, you can left every fund inside the crowdsale contract. But often crowdsale contracts are complex, and even if you have them audited a bug might be present. So if you want to protect funds you can move them to a simpler contract with less potential bugs.

One advantage TenX is that it is done automatically for every deposit, so you do not have to worry about it. In the EOS case someone has to do it manually, or setup a bot, and you have to check periodically that everything is running correctly.

So like everything it is a matter of security against costs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm thinking of doing something in-between.  See my 2017-08-25 update with my code to my original post.  Is this the best method or compromise?

Comment: A little problem with that approach is every 50 contributors there's an one unfortunate that has to pay for the other 49.

Comment: Vault.transfer(this.balance) is not run every 50 contributors. It's run after the contract's balance is > 50 ETH.  How does the contributor pay?  Are you saying that the gas for Vault.transfer(this.balance) comes from the last contributor's payment?

Comment: Yes, the contributor that trigger the transfer will pay more then the others. I think the major enemy for a smart contract is uncertainty, so I always prefer, as a developer and as a user, a clear choice and a clear and fixed cost model. Aso the boolean autosend controlled by owner it's very unpleasant imho.

Comment: My bad, I've read incorrectly the trigger was 50 contributors not 50 ethers. One possibility is to reward such users with some extra tokens, some kind of pinata, the unfortunate user get a small reward for their trouble.

Comment: So, it sounds like the best method is EOS, and not TenX nor my "compromise" method. Correct? If so, I will scrap my code pertaining to autoSend and Vault.transfer(this.balance) in "function createTokens".  I will let owner call "function collect", every once in a while.  (Vault starts off as owner's wallet address, which can be changed by the owner.  But there's no foreseeable need to change it.)  I wonder how much risk there is to leave funds on the contract & depend on manual withdrawals.  Has anyone heard of hackers taking advantage of this? Anyone know why EOS uses assert & not require?

Comment: There's no best or more secure method each one is suited for some purpose. For example some people like the contracts to be fully automatted with minimal or no intervention from the owner. It is just a matter of your target audience, and their expectations. If you follow large ICOs there was ten thousands of dollars used in fees alone, there were some complaints about the situation but everything remained the same.